# EcomDev PHPUnit: How to get product price including tax?

Tags: tax, vat, ecomdev-phpunit, phpunit

I'm trying to get product price both excluding and including tax in EcomDev_PHPUnit.

I have a fixture based on the one provided in official manual. I've put the following between *scope* and *eav*:

```
config:
  default/catalog/price/scope: 1 # Set price scope to website
  default/tax/calculation/algorithm: UNIT_BASE_CACLULATION
  default/tax/calculation/based_on: origin
  default/tax/calculation/apply_tax_on: 0
  default/tax/calculation/price_includes_tax: 0
  default/tax/calculation/apply_after_discount: 1
  default/tax/defaults/country: DE
  default/tax/defaults/region: 0
  default/tax/defaults/postcode: *
  default/tax/display/type: 2
  default/tax/sales_display/price: 1
tables:
  tax/tax_class:
    - class_id: 3
      class_name: Retail Customer
      class_type: CUSTOMER
  tax/tax_calculation_rate:
    - tax_calculation_rate_id: 3
      tax_country_id: DE
      tax_region_id: 12
      tax_postcode: *
      code: VAT
      rate: 19
  tax/tax_calculation_rule:
    - tax_calculation_rule_id: 1
      code: Retail Customer-VAT
      priority: 1
      position: 1
      calculate_subtotal: 0
  tax/tax_calculation:
    - tax_calculation_id: 3
      tax_calculation_rule_id: 1
      tax_calculation_rate_id: 3
      customer_tax_class_id: 3
      product_tax_class_id: 3
  customer/customer_group:
    - customer_group_id: 1
      customer_group_code: General
      tax_class_id: 3
```

The failing part of the test is:

```
$finalPriceInclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), true);
$finalPriceExclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), false);

// Check that prices including and excluding tax are different
$this->assertNotEquals(
    $finalPriceInclTax,
    $finalPriceExclTax
);
```

In both $finalPriceInclTax and $finalPriceExclTax I'm getting the price excluding tax.

Could you please help me with this fixture? I'm obviously missing something here.

**Notes:**

- I would very much prefer using a fixture to setting up tax in the test itself
- I need to get both prices on the catalog level (not checkout)

Answer (score 1):

The function getPrice() look like this

```
public function getPrice($product, $price, $includingTax = null, $shippingAddress = null, $billingAddress = null,
                         $ctc = null, $store = null, $priceIncludesTax = null, $roundPrice = true)
```

So try

```
$finalPriceInclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), true, null, null, null, null, false);
```

To get price including tax

Comment: Thanks for your answer @arshad, but passing default values for arguments doesn't change anything. Setting $roundPrice to either true or false does change function's output but still I get price excluding tax in both $finalPriceInclTax and $finalPriceExclTax.